# Why Byte Addressable Stores Limitation in OpenCL 1.0?

Tags: opencl

I'm quite new in OpenCL and reading [The OpenCL Specifications v1.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.x-latest.pdf#page=252) I saw that: in order to perform writes on pointers that are less than 32 bits in size the following directive must be included:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
```

My question is: 
Why was this limitation introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation exists because there is/was hardware (mostly GPUs) which only support 32 bit memory writes, meaning that 32 bit packed vector types (char4 for example) were the only way to write out small types. So the standard was engineered to the lowest common denominator and 32 bit write sizes were mandated.

However, as some OpenCL compatible devices did have memory controllers which support 16 or 8 bit size writes, the extension was added to allow small types to be directly written to memory without requiring packing into vector contains.

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082069/can-i-define-a-type-alias-depending-on-runtime-conditions-in-c).